# jQuery - Wrap page

Tags: jquery

I am using HTML + jQuery. At the moment, by html looks like this (#1):

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            other stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want the HTML to look like this from the beginning (#2):

```
<body>
    other stuff
</body>
```

I want to use jQuery to insert the #container and #wrapper to the DOM/HTML, shown in #1.
How do I do?

Comment: you want to start with empty body and inject the two divs ?

Comment: Do you want to insert content into these divs?

Comment: what are you planning to insert? and please look at the jquery docs first before you ask here

Comment: @Erik: Can you show what your body looks like now? if it's one child beneath `<body>` this is cake, otherwise it gets trickier.

Comment: @corroded: it's on topic, valid and encouraged to ask this type of question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76195/how-to-deal-with-have-you-tried-google-comments

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you meant, but those elements *are* already in the DOM. If you want to do that dynamically instead, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').append('<div id="container"><div id="wrapper">other stuff</div></div>');
});
```

And that's it

---

There is also a bit more "clean" way to do this, using javascript html templates. That would be like this:

```
<body>
  <!-- all your body content goes here -->
  <script type="text/html" id="mytemplate">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="wrapper">
        .. more stuff ..
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
</body>
```

And then in your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').append($('#mytemplate').text());
});
```

Notice the way the former script tag was defined as "text/html" instead of "text/javascript"

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

As per updated question:

```
$(function(){
  var content = $('body').html();
  $('body').html('<div id="container"><div id="wrapper">'+content+'</div></div>');
});
```

Comment: You realise that you could have just edited your original answer to include this, rather than adding an entirely *new* answer?

Comment: Lets pretend `content` is `<div id="abc">hi</div>` and I have `$('#abc').click(function() { });` in my javascript file. Do I need to use live() ($('#abc').live('click', function() { });) with this code?

Comment: @Erik: Yes, and this is probably another question.

Comment: @David: Ill delete my other question - thanks. I normally do this but for some reason decided that need to write a second answer.

Comment: @Kieran, okay, I wasn't trying to suggest that you **should** do it this way (or delete the other answer), I just wasn't sure if you knew that you could is all. Sorry... =)

Comment: @David: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78902/a-questions-is-edited-and-thus-the-answer-is-changed-what-should-be-done

Comment: @Kieran: ah, *interesting*. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
function CreateDIVTag(divId,divContent){
 var tag = document.createElement('div');
 tag.id= divId;
 tag.innerHTML = divContent; 
 return tag;
}
var content = 'blah blah blah';

$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').append(CreateDIVTag('container',CreateDIVTag('wrapper',content)));

});
```

I would do it something on this line. I am not too keen on stringy code and having markup directly in js code.